# How to add lstlisting to Algorithms List

Tags: listings, pseudocode

I have written a document where I use pseudo code to describe some general algorithms (with `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` ) which can be viewed at the begining after toc as „List of Algorithms”.

I also use some java code written using `\usepackage{listings}` to describe more code. I would like to also add these algorithms written in java to the List Of Algorithms among those written in pseudo code.

Is it possible?

Listings configuration:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\lstset{
  language=Java,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
  %numbers=left,               % Ort der Zeilennummern
  numberstyle=\tiny,          % Stil der Zeilennummern
  %stepnumber=2,               % Abstand zwischen den Zeilennummern
  numbersep=6pt,              % Abstand der Nummern zum Text
  tabsize=4,                  % Groesse von Tabs
  extendedchars=true,         %
  breaklines=true,            % Zeilen werden Umgebrochen
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray},
  stringstyle=\ttfamily, % Farbe der String
  showspaces=false,           % Leerzeichen anzeigen ?
  showtabs=false,             % Tabs anzeigen ?
  xleftmargin=17pt,
  framexleftmargin=17pt,
  framexrightmargin=5pt,
  framexbottommargin=4pt,
  %backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  showstringspaces=false,
  morekeywords={get,set,interface, null, var, in}
}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{black}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[cmyk]{0.13,0.14,0.10,0.1}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}
```

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115023/combine-listoflistings-and-listofalgorithms-into-one-list

Comment: Either add `lstlisting`s to the List of Algorithms or `algorithm`s or `algorithm`s to List of Listings. The latter is described in [egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115062/5764), while the former would just be a reverse of that. The big thing is to make them use the same counters and List-of extension.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Does the link by Marco Daniel help?

Comment: Not really. I coudnt add the listlings to the loa. I dont get any error it just doesnt do anything...it shows only one of them. I tried coppy paste to that code...same, i have only the listlings.
I wrote in the original message how i print the loa.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility; [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) was used to patch the internal `\lst@MakeCaption` (from `listings`) so the caption is written in the `.loa` file (used for `\listofalgorithms`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lst@MakeCaption}{\addcontentsline{lol}}{\addcontentsline{loa}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\lst@MakeCaption}{\addcontentsline{lol}}{\addcontentsline{loa}}{}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\c@lstlisting\c@algorithm
  \let\thelstlisting\thealgorithm
  \renewcommand\listalgorithmname{List of algorithms}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}
This is an algorithm
\caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A listing]
This is a listing
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{algorithm}
This is another algorithm
\caption{Another algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Another listing]
This is another listing
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now that the original question has been edited, the code from my previous example has to be placed *before* loading `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{courier}

% Before loading subcaption %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lst@MakeCaption}{\addcontentsline{lol}}{\addcontentsline{loa}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\lst@MakeCaption}{\addcontentsline{lol}}{\addcontentsline{loa}}{}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\c@lstlisting\c@algorithm
  \let\thelstlisting\thealgorithm
  \renewcommand\listalgorithmname{List of algorithms}
}
\makeatother
% Before loading subcaption %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{subcaption}
\lstset{
  language=Java,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
  %numbers=left,               % Ort der Zeilennummern
  numberstyle=\tiny,          % Stil der Zeilennummern
  %stepnumber=2,               % Abstand zwischen den Zeilennummern
  numbersep=6pt,              % Abstand der Nummern zum Text
  tabsize=4,                  % Groesse von Tabs
  extendedchars=true,         %
  breaklines=true,            % Zeilen werden Umgebrochen
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray},
  stringstyle=\ttfamily, % Farbe der String
  showspaces=false,           % Leerzeichen anzeigen ?
  showtabs=false,             % Tabs anzeigen ?
  xleftmargin=17pt,
  framexleftmargin=17pt,
  framexrightmargin=5pt,
  framexbottommargin=4pt,
  %backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  showstringspaces=false,
  morekeywords={get,set,interface, null, var, in}
}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{black}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[cmyk]{0.13,0.14,0.10,0.1}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}


\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}
This is an algorithm
\caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A listing]
This is a listing
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{algorithm}
This is another algorithm
\caption{Another algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Another listing]
This is another listing
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't work. I get no errors but the listings are not displayed. I guess there is something wrong with the way i write them. I edited the first post and wrote the entire configuration. Can you find something wrong?

Comment: @Cry0nicS please see my updated answer. The code I suggested has to appear *before* loading `subcaption`, as in my second example code.